# Почему hover применяется только к border

Tags: html, css

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 3.95px;
  background-color: #131129;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-property: all;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid #e3e3e5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.checkbox_input::before {
  content: "";
  background: url('img');
  background-color: #6e6794;
  width: 16.3px;
  height: 16.3px;
  border-radius: 2.9px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  right: 918px;
  margin: -20px 0 0 0;
  color: #131129;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox:checked+.checkbox_input::before {
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkbox:hover {
  background-color: #6e6794;
  border-color: #c7c7ff;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="label">
    <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox checkbox_input" name="">
    <div class="checkbox_input"></div>
  </label>
```

Comment: При наведении фон тоже меняется..

Comment: не меняется тут когда я убираю фото,то эта проблема уходит,как думаешь можно исправить?

Comment: @Артём какое фото?

Comment: решил данную проблему,заключалась в в z-index